# Search engine - how to handle empty queries

Tags: javascript, php, html

New to this group. Need tip to ignore empty search box queries. The following code works fine but when I click the search button with nothing in the text field, it gives me all my page links as results. I would want no action for an empty box search...thanks in advance folks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='./search.php' method='get'>       
        <input type='text' name='k' size='15' value='<?php echo isset($_GET['k']) ? $_GET['k'] : ""; ?>' placeholder=' ' />
        <input type="image" src="images/magnifier.png"  width="14"  height="14" border="0" >
    </form>


    <h2>Search Results</h2>
    <hr />
    <?php

        $k = isset($_GET['k']) ? $_GET['k'] : "";

        $terms = explode(" ", $k);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($terms as $each){
            $i++;               
            if ($i == 1)
                $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
            else
                $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
        }


        // connect to DB
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "mypwd");
        mysql_select_db("busqueda");

        $query = mysql_query($query);
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($numrows > 0) {

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];   
                $link = $row['link'];   

                echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2>
                $description<br /><br />";  

                    //empty query variable before coming back to home page
                    $k = null;

            }
        }
        else
            echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";
            //empty query variable before coming back to home page
                    $k = null;

            //disconnect from DB
            mysql_close();

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this going to be a production site. If so please use **PDO** of **MySQLI**. Your current method for sending queries is deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't do anything if you get an empty query

```
if (empty($_GET['k']) or trim($_GET['k']) == ''){
    exit;// or something
}
```

also you can prevent the form from submitting an empty query with the required attribute

```
<form action='./search.php' method='get'>       
    <input type='text' name='k' required size='15' value='<?php echo isset($_GET['k']) ? $_GET['k'] : ""; ?>' placeholder=' ' />
    <input type="image" src="images/magnifier.png"  width="14"  height="14" border="0" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

before getting to

```
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
```

check if $k is not empty

```
if($k !=''){
// put here your query structure and database stuff 
// now    we are sure that there is some content in the k field
```

}

Comment: All awesome answers folks! I used the not empty approach and echo'd "no results found - empty search". This is simply enough for my site. Very much appreciated guys!

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the rest of your code after defining $k with and if statement like so:

```
if($k != ""){
   //execute search
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If required='true' is not enough (at the client-side), as you might want to  prevent a submit (codes assumes jQuery usage) and do some stuff:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() { // replace by form #id selector
        if ($(this).find('[name=k]').val().trim() == '') {
            return false;  // do other stuff, as warn user
        }
    });
});
```